# Getting full path for a resource in Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a POST method at

`http://example.com/rest/cars`

returning JSON representation of the newly created object.

How can I build the full path for interacting with the created resource? Example locations could be

`http://example.com/rest/cars/1`

or

`http://anotherdomain.com/rest/cars/1`

I want to fetch the domain part dynamically inside the application. I have tried *org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext* and several other places, but to no success. Has anyone done this?

I use Spring framework and deploy in Tomcat if that changes anything...

Edit:

Following comment asking about what I try to achieve:

```
String domainPart = "http://howdoigethis.com"; // need to fetch domain dynamically
Integer id = 1;
String selfLocationOfId1 = domainPart + "/rest/cars/" + id;
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of what you're trying to achieve? I don't quite understand the *fetch the domain part dynamically inside the application*.

Comment: @aribeiro see my edit above

Comment: Do you mean make a request to another web server actually and return its result?

Comment: @KristjanVeskimäe, assuming that you're on the server side, and that the server knows its own IP address, why don't you follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3371993/1346996) approach?