# Get name of computer from ipaddress

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the name of computer from its local IP. This is what I've done so far, but nothing works it just returns the IP address as hostname

```
InetAddress addr = null;
String hostIP = "192.168.100.10";

try {
    addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostIP);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.out.println("Host " + hostIP + " not found!");
}

String host = addr.getHostAddress();
String hostname= addr.getHostName();
String hostname2 = addr.getCanonicalHostName();
```

I am expecting to get DESKTOP-DWASDFW as hostname but instead i get 192.168.100.10

**UPDATE:**
I managed to "fix" it by adding my computer and its ip address manually into the router configuration

[image: https://i.imgur.com/6yDK91v.png]

but this isn't what im looking for as it requires manually entering every name and IP address. I want something like this app [WakeOnLan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.mrwebb.wakeonlan&hl=en), it can scan the whole network and get IP address, MAC address and hostname. This app uses arp requests, i researched a lot about how to accomplish something like that in android but found nothing that worked for me (I'm using android 4.2.2)

Comment: Does your network meet the requirements stated in the docs for doing the name lookup service?

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371879/ip-address-to-hostname-in-java

Comment: @DaveNewton i believe it does because I've used numerous android applications that scan the whole network, like WakeOnLan gives me the ip adress along with the name of the pc just by a search, zANTI also does a full network search and gives me ip adress and name, so i believe my network supports that but i have no idea how to do it

Comment: @SalehMahmood already tried all that, the getlocaladdress() returns localhost as name but other than that everything else gives me back the IP address